# int int.operator(int left, int right) &

Tags: c#

I try to understand this expression:

```
 static Func<int, bool> isOdd = i => (i & 1) == 1;
```

But what does this mean?

for example I have i = 3. Then (3 & 1) == 1

or i = 4. Then (4 & 1) == 1

I don't understand this. How can it determine when it is odd or when it is even.

with this method:

```
public static void Hallo2()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                if (isOdd(i))
                    Console.WriteLine(i + " is odd");
                else
                    Console.WriteLine(i + " is even");
            }

        }
```

Thank you

Comment: Hint: What does `&` mean?

Comment: Well, `(3 & 1) == 1` is true. `(4 & 1) == 1` is false. So is `3` odd? True. Is `4` odd? False.

Comment: Yes, oke. But how to read the &? so 3  or 1 == 1? but that doesn't make sense. So how to read the &?

Comment: `&` is bitwise _and_, not or. You should find it easily by searching for "c# operators".

Comment: Ok. Thank you. So if i is odd and 1 is odd then expression is odd?

Comment: @LikeToDo - Not really, it's more like if `i & 1` is `1` and `1` is `1` then the expression is odd.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`&` is bitwise AND operation .net uses 32 bit integers but for this example I will use 4 bits, with the left bit being the least significant bit.

The operation 3 & 1. Looks at the numbers in binary so 0011 and 0001 and will output the number where both values are . 1000 = 1.

4 & 1 is 0100 and 0001 so 0000 = 0

It's basically checking if the first (or least significant bit) is 1, if it is we know the number is odd.

Comment: ah, oke. THank you

Comment: 3 is 0011, 4 is 0100 and 1 is 0001 to clarify

Answer (score 4):

Try to convert it to bits so you can visualize it:

3 = `0011`, while 1 = `0001`. So `0011 & 0001` will result with `0001`.
If you did 3 & 2 == 2 you would also get true since `0011 & 0010` will result with `0010`.
Similarly, 8 & 2 == 2 will result with false, since 8 is `0100` and 2 is `0010`, so the result of a bitwise and will be `0000`.

Answer (score 1):

You have mistaken & logical operator with binary & bitwise operator.

> or i = 4. Then (4 & 1) == 1

This is not true, since 4 in binary format is 0b100 and when you calculate in binary you will get `0b100 & 0b001 == 0;` The same applies to `3 & 1` will result in `0b11 & 0b01 == 1`. Therefore method works as expected. As all odd numbers always have the least significant bit set to 1 this is the fastest and simplest method to test if number is odd. The reverse is true for even numbers.

Comment: I guess simplest is debatable. To me the % operator used like X % 2 seems more intuitive and thus simple to check for odd or even. The & operator is probably the best, even if not as intuitive. It just takes a few minutes to understand.